# interfacing c++ to control motor stepper with arduino

Tags: c++, serial-port, arduino

I have tried to control motor stepper via arduino uno board with slider in visual C++.

but the servo didnot move at all.

here the program at PC side:

```
void CENVSConfigDlg::OnBnClickedButton1() 
{ 
 SetTimer(cTimer1,80,NULL); 
  }

 void CENVSConfigDlg::OnTimer(UINT_PTR ID)
 { 
   if(ID==cTimer1){ 
    DWORD nbytes;
    char buf[5]; 
    sprintf(buf, "%d \n", val_test);
     /* Open serial port. */ 
       if(!WriteFile( hnd_serial, (void*)buf, 5, &nbytes, NULL )){MessageBox(L"Write Com Port fail!");return;} 
 }
```

and the program in arduino:

```
 #include <Servo.h> 
 Servo servoMain;

int index=0; 
String inputString;

void setup() 
{ 
Serial.begin(9600);
servoMain.attach(9);
}

void loop() 
{ 
  int data;
while (Serial.available()) 
{ 
char inChar = (char)Serial.read(); 
if (inChar == '\n' || inChar == 'z') 
{
  data=stringToInt(inputString); 
Serial.println(data); //
inputString=""; 

servoMain.write(data); //tambahannya
delay(50);

break; 
} 
if (inChar != 0)
{ 
inputString += inChar;
} 
} 
}

int stringToInt(String s)
{ 
char char_string[s.length()+1]; 
 s.toCharArray(char_string, s.length()+1); 
 return atoi(char_string);
 }
```

the pc i think is sending the data, but why the motor didnot working? any idea?

Comment: Divide and conquer.  First make sure the servo works by running the *sweep* sample program.  Next make sure the serial port works by sending back what you receive.  Next ponder how the 4 bytes you send with the PC is going to be handled one byte at a time on your Arduino, that of course can't work.  Improve your PC program by sending a single byte instead of ASCII

Comment: I have tried using potentiometer and motor servo is working well, I have changed the arduino program, but the servo right now always in max position, eventhough I change the value

Comment: You are sending garbage, the last byte your PC sends is 0.  The string terminator.  You are also overflowing the buffer if val_test is larger than 9, very bad.  As I said, focus on sending a single byte.

Comment: \n I needed for arduino to change from char to int, but I will try to send a single byte.

Answer (score 0):

First off, does the serial link work at all?  The number of ways that an RS232 link can not work, for both hardware and software reasons, is legendary.  Unless you can show that the hardware can transfer data, it's pointless to look at your dedicated software.  If you have a scope, use that to see if anything is being transmitted and then check that it arrives at the correct pin on the arduino input.  If you have no access to a scope, a small LED and a 4.7K resistor can be used to indicate that there is data on the line - it will flicker with the data.

Comment: I have edit the program, The pc program can turn on and off the led (using if else). When I apply on motor servo program, the motor rotate to max eventhough I set the value 0-90 (the max is 180 degree)